# Killing Queued Notification Balloons (Pre-Vista)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system-tray, balloon

I have a non-MFC, non-ATL C++ app that routinely creates notification balloons on a system tray icon. If, on pre-Vista boxes, the user locks the screen - these newly created "[balloons are queued](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28VS.85%29.aspx)", which creates a mess when the user finally logs back in.  There could be dozens or hundreds of balloons waiting.  The timeout set for each balloon does not apply until the user logs back in!!

So to solve this, I need to know either:

1. Is there a way to cancel any outstanding balloon I made, when a new balloon arrives?
2. Should I instead check for a "session lock" / "screen lock" and stop creating balloons in the user's absence?

Regarding option #2, what message do I listen for in the windows loop to capture an account lock / session lock?  I tried the event WM_ENDSESSION, but my app acted like it didn't see it.  Is that the right event?  Do I need to register for it?

Of course if there is a simpler way to solve this, I'd love to know.  Certainly for Vista and later, the [NIF_REALTIME uFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) option solves the problem handily.

p.s. I'm appalled that I can't find a list of windows messages online with descriptions.  All I found was a [list without descriptions](http://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages), and it isn't even hosted by Microsoft!!!

Comment: For a rather large (but still not complete) categorized list of window messages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927.aspx#system_defined

Comment: Why are you creating dozens or hundreds of balloons?  I think your application would drive me insane.

Comment: @Luke: Have a half-dozen balloons an hour, and log-out from the "test machine" for a two week vacation.  Come back and "balloon-mania."

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to show a balloon every 10 minutes?  IMHO this is a misuse of the notification area (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511497.aspx).  As for your issue, you should separate the balloon stuff out into a separate application so it can exit when the user logs off.  Doesn't solve the problem of the user walking away from the computer for an hour, though.

Comment: @Luke: More precisely, I do not have a "need" for copious balloons.  It is a thin UI wrapped over legacy code whose messaging I cannot alter, I'm only permitted to fix this particular bug. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding option (2) you need to register interest in 'SessionNotifications', using the function [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
WTSRegisterSessionNotification(HWND hWnd, DWORD dwFlags);
```

You pass in the handle to the window to receive the message [WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and use the flag NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION, which indicates you want to get messages when session events occur.

Session events you would be interested in are WTS_SESSION_LOCK and WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK. Please bear in mind that you must use the corresponding deregister function [WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(HWND hWnd);
```

You need to keep track of the locked/unlocked/connected/disconnected state of the session, which allows you to decide when to schedule balloon messages.

Comment: Excellent stuff. I think my problem now is, evidently, that approach does not work for Windows 2000. So now I'm looking at WinLogin Notification Packages `http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721961(WS.10).aspx`.  Of course I'm still interested in a solution addressing 'approach #1' I had listed.  In other words, why can't those balloons just manage themselves?

Comment: Winlogon notification packages were deprecated in Vista.  Before you show the balloon you could call GetLastInputInfo(); if the last user input was more than X minutes ago you don't show the balloon.

Comment: @Brend Arias - True, this is only supported for Windows XP and later. If you want something that supports Windows 2000 - you could go looking into the 'System Event Notification Services' (SENS). There is a demo application available here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321381 This is supported from Win2K and up.